# manipulate cursor position from an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, cursor

I have a very wide question here, and I hope I can clearly explain what exactly I need.

The image below shows a circle, which is a html element. I wanted to create an interactive element and play with the cursor. Imagine that for some reason, you can't put your cursor inside the circle. I don't want to just hide the cursor if you approach the circle, but manipulate the cursor in a way that moves your cursor away in a sort of magnetic attraction.

So: If you put your cursor around the circle, it will never approach it and be sent away from this element. is that somehow possible to do? Javascript, Angular or something else? Does anyway have ever created something like that?

[image]

Comment: would it be suitable to move the circle away from the cursor? That seems more realistically possible

Comment: Haven't used it but the [pointer lock API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_Lock_API) might be relevant here.

Comment: @hairmot I thought about it, but the concept is the opposite. Is like a metaphor, that nothing can penetrates the circle. not even the cursor.

Answer (score 1):

you can use following method
Hide cursor permanently and use div element instead. 
On window mouse move event change position of that div element with current location of pointer. 
Now You need to put condition here that when ever pointer enters in circle region 
do not update div element position with current position of pointer instead of this update it with new calculated position which is outside of circle.

If you need code then i can provide it to you.

Comment: wow, this sounds amazing! I will try to do it, but if you have an example, will be appreciated!

Comment: try following link 

https://jsfiddle.net/spankajd/5h066zwt/1/


but for region detect i need add some more code 
do you want that also ?

Comment: thank you! that's solve 60% of the problem :) But,  it must be two elements: the cursor (your circle in the case) can't penetrate another element, just be around. check this - http://jsfiddle.net/hj57k/3764/
it might have a way to keep the cursor (the small div) around the big div, and not allowing it to be inside.